# Subtract 10 days from Date in sql (date format P20221025)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have date in format P20221025. How to subtract 10 days from date in WHERE clause to limit data?
I need date = P20221025 - 10 days.

Comment: `P20221025` is not a date, so you first need to convert it to a date and perform subtraction. These are two different tasks/questions

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type comprised of 7 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second); it **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored with a (human-readable) format.

> I have date in format P20221025.

Then you either:

1. Do not have a date, and probably have a string; or
2. Do have a date and it has no format.

---

If you do have a date then just use subtraction:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  a_date_column = :your_date_value - 10;
```

Or, if you want to match a 24-hour period then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  a_date_column >= :your_date_value - 10
AND    a_date_column <  :your_date_value -  9;
```

---

If you have a string then convert it to a date:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  a_date_column = TO_DATE(:your_string_value, '"P"YYYYMMDD') - 10;
```

Or, if you want to match a 24-hour period then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  a_date_column >= TO_DATE(:your_string_value, '"P"YYYYMMDD') - 10
AND    a_date_column <  TO_DATE(:your_string_value, '"P"YYYYMMDD') -  9;
```